# How to open an internal page using a Universal Link in iOS

Tags: swift, deep-linking, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication, ios-universal-links

So, I use a 3rd party SDK, CleverTap, for analytics which also sends out in-app notifications - for which I have to provide a URL.

Now Universal links from an external app work fine on my app, however, when I `UIApplication.shared.open()` the same `Universal Link` I am redirected to Safari.

How to not redirect to Safari and get the expected callback in the AppDelegate

Comment: Before you open link, just check that it's your link or not!